# Regex match only if last group is exactly n characters long

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will match a pattern, but not match if the last group is not exactly 4 characters long.

Example:
Regex: (.{1,}-)(.{1,}-)(.{1,}-)(\d{4,4})
Good input: A-AAAA-A-0001
Bad input: A-AAAA-A-00011

My Regex fails, it picks up A-AAAA-A-0001 from both inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex will pick up matches from inside of a string (i.e. it will find matching substrings):

```
(?<=\s|^)([^\s]+-){3}(\d{4})(?=\s|$)
```

The following will pick up matches for the whole string only

```
^([^\s]+-){3}(\d{4})$
```

I've simplified your regex a bit, but made the assumption that you weren't using each group of characters for something.

I turned your:

```
(.{1,}-)(.{1,}-)(.{1,}-)
```

Into

```
([^\s]+-){3}
```

Which says "match anything that isn't whitespace and ends with a dash exactly 3 times. The '+' operator is shorthand for saying {1,] or "at least once".

**Can we be more specific?**

I suspect that you're probably only wanting to match alphanumeric values. For example, I'm doubting that `$-A%^A-@-0001` is a valid match for you. If I'm right about this, you'll want to use a shorthand character class, which would make your regex look like this instead (I'm assuming your regex is case sensitive):

Match Substrings:

```
(?<=\s|^)([A-Za-z\d]+-){3}(\d{4})(?=\s|$)
```

Match Whole Strings:

```
^([A-Za-z\d]+-){3}(\d{4})$
```

**A couple of pointers:**

- Instead of specifying `{4,4}` to say "exactly 4 times", just use
  `{4}`
- Instead of specifying `{1,}` to say "1 or more times", just use
  `+`
- `(?={regex in here})` means, look ahead in the string and match the following, but don't add it to my result (it's called a positive lookahead)
- `(?<={regex in here})` means, look backwards in the string and match the following, but don't add it to my result (it's called a positive lookbehind)
- There are also negative lookarounds that do the opposite, but I'll leave that to you to research.

Comment: If you're keen on Regex, which for some reason I am, you might want to look into an application called RegexBuddy. It's awesome for beginners right through to experts. You can insert test data and write your regex and see what matches it pulls out in real time. It also has really good context help, a visual regex builder that decodes a regex into plain english and it can also export your completed regex to any number of programming languages (it'll also warn you if you're using something unsupported in your language). I'm not affiliated with the folks who make it at all I just love the product

Answer (score 2):

Anchor your regular expression with `^` and `$` for beginning and end of a string correspondingly.

If it's not the whole string then the negative lookahead assertion would help you `(?!\d)`

References:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx (search for "negative lookahead assertion" string)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd advise you to simplify your Regex a little bit. My suggestion is:

```
(\w+-){3}(\d{4})
```

Since you have **3 groups** of **word characters** followed by a `-` sign, this is pretty straightforward.

Now, in order to capture only those desired matches, *if you are testing exactly those strings*, you only need to add the `^` and `$` delimiters.

```
^(\w+-){3}(\d{4})$
```

Please check [this Regex101 link](http://regex101.com/r/pO6aM5) to see it in action.